# Create a variable that is equal to a value from another (grouped) observation

Tags: r, dplyr, case

First, thanks for anyone who has contributed to this website. It has helped me so much in figuring out R.

I have a data set that is structured like this (very oversimplified example):

```
#> Var 1   Var2 Var 3    Var 4    Var5
#>  1         1 1         A        1200
#>  2         1 2         A        2300
#>  3         1 1         A        1200
#>  4         2 2         A        2300
#>  5         2 1         B        1200
#>  6         3 2         B        2300
#>  7         3 1         B        1200
#>  8         3 2         B        2300
#>  9         3 1         B        1200
#> 10         4 2         B        2300
```

I would like to (1) group the data together based on Var 1, Var 2, and Var 3; this tends to create groups of two rows. Within those pairings, I would then like to (2) create a new variable (Var 6) based on the values of Var 4 and Var 5 for the other observation in the pairing. In step (2), I would basically like to create a variable that swaps the observations of Var 5 for each pair.

Code looks like this:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Var1, Var2, Var3) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Var6 = case_when(Var5 == A ~ Var5[Var5 == B]), Var5 == B ~ Var5[Var5 == A])
)
```

```
Output should look like this: 

#> Var 1   Var2 Var 3    Var 4    Var5    Var 6
#>  1         1 1         A        1200    2300
#>  2         1 2         A        2300    1200
#>  3         1 1         A        1200    2300
#>  4         2 2         A        2300    1200
#>  5         2 1         B        1200    2300
#>  6         3 2         B        2300    1200
#>  7         3 1         B        1200    2300
#>  8         3 2         B        2300    1200
#>  9         3 1         B        1200    2300
#> 10         4 2         B        2300    1200
```

With the code above, I'm getting the following error message:

```
`Var 6` must be size 1, not 0.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% ...
 9. dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)
```

Comment: The example data provided dos not produce groups of two rows. All groups are one-row long. This is fairly obvious since Var1 is a sequence.

Comment: Even "oversimplified" examples should reproduce the data structure adequately, consider reviewing the question

Comment: You are comparing Var5 with undeclared variables `A` and `B`. Were you trying to compare with the string values `"A"` and `"B"`? Even then, it would not make any sense because Var5 is numeric, and should not usually be compared to strings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to change `Var1` and then group solely on that, so that we can get groups of 2 rows. I'll also make sure we have a couple of groups with 1 row only, for demonstration of the value-swapping logic. You won't need the first `mutate` with your real data, we'll assume that it has sufficient variability to give you the 2-rows you say you expect.

```r
df1 %>%
  mutate(Var1 = replace(rep(1:5, each=2), 10, 6)) %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  mutate(Var6 = if (n() == 1) Var5 else rev(Var5)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 6
#     Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4   Var5  Var6
#    <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int>
#  1     1     1     1 A      1200  2300
#  2     1     1     2 A      2300  1200
#  3     2     1     1 A      1200  2300
#  4     2     2     2 A      2300  1200
#  5     3     2     1 B      1200  2300
#  6     3     3     2 B      2300  1200
#  7     4     3     1 B      1200  2300
#  8     4     3     2 B      2300  1200
#  9     5     3     1 B      1200  1200
# 10     6     4     2 B      2300  2300
```

This does rely on their being groups of only 1 or 2 rows, never more. If that's a factor, then the `rev(.)` hack is likely to break down. If that's the case, then we need to come up with logic when there are multiple rows.

For that, we can produce a simple function that takes the first value once "this row's" value has been removed. In fact, I'll give you a two options:

- **Var6a**: negative indexing (`Var5[-i][1]`) ensures that this row's value is removed and we take the first remaining value; if for some reason you have repeat `Var5` in a group, then this might result in the same value
- **Var6c**: `setdiff`, which removes this row's value from the candidates and returns the first remaining value; if you have repeat `Var5` in a group, this method guarantees that you will not get the same value

For each of those two, I also provide a cleanup operation using `coalesce` in case you *must* have a value in `Var6`, defaulting to the original `Var5`. This is useful when a group has only 1 row or when `Var5` is invariant.

```r
df1 %>%
  mutate(Var1 = replace(rep(1:5, each=2), 10, 6)) %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  mutate(
    Var6a = sapply(row_number(), function(i) Var5[-i][1]), 
    Var6b = coalesce(Var6a, Var5), 
    Var6c = sapply(Var5, function(v5) setdiff(Var5, v5)[1]), 
    Var6d = coalesce(Var6c, Var5)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 9
#     Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4   Var5 Var6a Var6b Var6c Var6d
#    <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1     1     1 A      1200  2300  2300  2300  2300
#  2     1     1     2 A      2300  1200  1200  1200  1200
#  3     2     1     1 A      1200  2300  2300  2300  2300
#  4     2     2     2 A      2300  1200  1200  1200  1200
#  5     3     2     1 B      1200  2300  2300  2300  2300
#  6     3     3     2 B      2300  1200  1200  1200  1200
#  7     4     3     1 B      1200  2300  2300  2300  2300
#  8     4     3     2 B      2300  1200  1200  1200  1200
#  9     5     3     1 B      1200    NA  1200    NA  1200
# 10     6     4     2 B      2300    NA  2300    NA  2300
```

For all of these methods, I'm using `sapply` since without it we'd be doing a vector-long operation. For instance, `Var5[-row_number()]` removes all elements from the vector, so we cannot extract the "other". Hence, we use `sapply` to do things element-wise; internally, the `i` (index counter) or `v5` ("this value of `Var5`") is always length-1, but referencing `Var5` inside of the `sapply(.., FUN=)` does reference the entire vector/column, so we're able to extract the non-matching value(s).